# JQuery Autocomplete: Get the currently focused <li>

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

JQuery Autocomplete triggers a focus event when the user mouses over or otherwise highlights one of its `<li>` options. Within this event, I want to refer to the `<li>` that is currently focused, but I can't figure out how to select it. At the moment, I have:

```
focus: function( event, ui ) {
  var target = event.currentTarget
  alert($(target).html())
}
```

But this returns the whole list of `<li>`s, rather than just the currently focused one. I've tried other event methods, such as event.delegateTarget and event.target, but with no success. Is there another way to get the focused element?

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle example

Comment: `console.log(ui)`. it's in there.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: No, it's not. That's the *item* being focused, not the `li`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're going to have to:

1. Grab the menu widget that autocomplete is using.
2. Get the `li` that's currently focused (this `li` has an `a` with class `ui-state-focus`

   ```
   focus: function (event, ui) {
       var menu = $(this).data("uiAutocomplete").menu.element,
       focused = menu.find("li:has(a.ui-state-focus)");
       // focused is the focused `li`
   }
   ```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/J5rVP/43/

Answer (score 1):

Are there any drawbacks when using the following instead?

```
focus: function(event, ui) {
    $(".ui-autocomplete li").removeClass("ui-state-hover");
    $(".ui-autocomplete").find("li:has(a.ui-state-focus)").addClass("ui-state-hover");
}
```

Comment: It's been awhile since I was dealing with this issue, but if I remember correctly, the problem with ui-state-focus was that it applied to the `ul` instead of the individuality focused `li`.

Comment: You really have the perfect solution. I was trying before solutions like applying .ui-state-focus and it doesn't work even after giving important in my case. Thanks a lot for the help.